# How to reference draft email where there are forms?

Tags: vba, outlook, userform

The user creates an email then clicks on the Send button, and a form will appear and there are options to send.
One option is to send an email and the recipient will receive the message on their mobile phone. When he selects this option, another form will appear to enter the mobile number and confirm with the button on the form to submit.

The problem is receiving the current draft e-mail message `Set objMail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem` generates an error message

> Object variable or With block variable not set

Without forms the code works.

1] first form is called from `ThisOutlookSession`

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    FormSending.Show
End Sub
```

Code of ButtonSend and Call main function from module `SendWithSms`

```
Private Sub ButtonSend_Click()
    Dim intDelta As Integer

    Call SendWithSms
    
    blnContinue = True
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

2] second form is in form folder and is called from function `SendWithSms`

```vb
'....
    User_form.Show
        
    If blnContinue = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    .Send
End With
'....
```

Is possible to identify the email message to be sent where there are forms?

Comment: I saw that you just updated this old question. I just tested with a modal form in Outlook, and Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem correctly identified the window title. What do you mean by "does not work because of forms"?

Comment: Anyway, sometimes we think that the CurrentItem is the one that we want, and it is not...  what appears at Immediate window when you break the code and do `?Application.ActiveInspector.Caption` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution:

to `ThisOutlookSession` add this part of code

```
Public objMail As Outlook.mailItem

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
      Dim objMail As Outlook.mailItem
      Dim CurrentItem As Object
    
      Set objMail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

      FormSending.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim objMail As Outlook.mailItem` will make `Public objMail As Outlook.mailItem` useless. If you will need it, it will be `Nothing`... I would suggest you to remove the declaration from the above `Sub`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `Show` method in your custom form with a parameter which can deliver an instatnce of the Outlook item for which the form is displayed, so you could pass it instantly:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
   If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
     FormSending.Show Item
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can check out the item type before invoking the `form.Show` method. The `ItemSend` event handler fires for all kinds of Outlook items. The `TypeName` function returns the class name.

Comment: still error ````Type mismatch````, maybe its not even possible to do this :(

Comment: or maybe when form show up, save all values to text file such as ````.TO````, ````.BC````, ````.Subject````, etc. and can be called back in main function from the file?